# How to create GTM variable from dataLayer array?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have no problems creating GTM variables from 'simple' dataLayer, 
example:

```
"transactionEntity": "ORDER",
"transactionId": "193552702",
```

But can't understand how to take values from array.
Basically i need to take ID value from these dataLayer table:

```
"transactionProducts":     [
      {
        "id": "5",
        "sku": "black-handbag",
        "price": 170,
        "priceexcludingtax": "0.00",
        "tax": "0.00",
        "taxrate": 0,
        "type": "bundle",
        "category": "",
        "quantity": 1
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "sku": "red-handbag",
        "price": 120,
        "priceexcludingtax": "0.00",
        "tax": "0.00",
        "taxrate": 0,
        "type": "bundle",
        "category": "",
        "quantity": 1
      }
    ],
```

And to pass them to FB pixel using this format:

```
content_ids: ['5', '3'],
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have datalayer like that:

```
<script>
dataLayer.push({
  'ecommerce': {
     "transactionProducts":     [
      {
        "id": "5",
        "sku": "black-handbag",
        "price": 170,
        "priceexcludingtax": "0.00",
        "tax": "0.00",
        "taxrate": 0,
        "type": "bundle",
        "category": "",
        "quantity": 1
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "sku": "red-handbag",
        "price": 120,
        "priceexcludingtax": "0.00",
        "tax": "0.00",
        "taxrate": 0,
        "type": "bundle",
        "category": "",
        "quantity": 1
      }
    ]
  }
});
</script>
```

And you want to create variable which will return array of IDs `['5', '3']`

**Then you need to create two variables:**

1) Name: `transactionProducts`

Type: `Data Layer Variable`

Data Layer Variable Name: `ecommerce.transactionProducts`

2) Name: `transactionProductsIds`

Type: `Custom JavaScript`

Custom JavaScript: `function () { return {{transactionProducts}}.map(function(a) {return a.id;}); }`

And then you can use your second variable `transactionProductsIds` to receive IDs